# Modifying the call stack

Tags: c++, stack-trace

Is it possible to modify the call stack in c++?  (I realize this is a horrible idea and am really just wondering----I don't plan on actually doing this)

For example:

```
void foo(){
  other();
  cout << "You never see this" << endl;  //The other() function modifies the stack to 
                            //point to what ever called this function...so this is not displayed
}
void other(){
  //modify the stack pointer here somehow to go down 2 levels
}

//Elsewhere
foo();
```

Comment: Yes you can.  But you need to know what a stack frame looks like.  And that is compiler and platform dependent.  What OS and compiler are you using?

Comment: 1. throw an exception, 2. `setjmp`/`longjmp`

Comment: @RichardHodges I am really only asking for curiosity sake (so I don't actually have a problem that needs to be solved)

Comment: @RichardHodges And what is `setjmp/longjmp`

Comment: @DarthRubik Read the manpages for each function.

Comment: @RichardHodges THAT IS SO AWESOME

Comment: One possible reason is to implement tail recursion like Forth does by removing the return address and then calling the function again.

Answer (score 1):

When a function calls another one in typical C implementations, the processor stack is used and the call opcode is used. That has as effect to push the next to execute processor instuction pointer on the processor stack. Usually besides the return address also the value of the stack frame pointer is used.
So the stack contains:
...free_space... [local_variables] [framePtr] [returnAddr] PREVIOUS_STACK.

So in order to change the return address ( that you should know what size it has -- if you compile e.g. via -m64 it will have as size of 64 bits ) you may get the address of a variable and add some to it in order to arrive to the address of the return pointer and change it.
The code bellow has been compiled with g++ in mode m64. 
If it works by change also for you you may see the effect.

```
#include <stdio.h>


void changeRetAddr(long* p){
    p-=2;
    *p+=0x11;
}


void myTest(){
    long a=0x1122334455667788;
    changeRetAddr(&a);
    printf("hi my friend\n");
    printf("I didn't showed the salutation\n");
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ 
    myTest();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By assembly debugging :-)

Comment: You don't need to derive constants via "assembly debugging" to do this... see my answer which doesn't need that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78111502/2147204

Answer (score 0):

The answer by George Kourtis involves hardcoded constants, for which the correct value needs to be manually determined by dumping the binary. We don't need to do that, provided we can use some GCC extensions – in particular `&&LABEL` which lets us take the address of a goto label, and `__builtin_frame_address(0)` which gives us the pointer to our stack frame.

Here is a test C program (although it works when compiled as C++ as well). It demos something similar to Fortran 77's "alternate return" feature, in which a function can be passed an alternative return address as an argument.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void alt_return_demo(void* return_to) {
        void *ra = __builtin_return_address(0);
        void *fa = __builtin_frame_address(0);
        printf("alt_return_demo: called with:\n");
        printf("\treturn_to=%p\n", return_to);
        printf("\treturn_address=%p\n", __builtin_return_address(0));
        printf("\tframe_address=%p\n", __builtin_frame_address(0));
        printf("\tframe_address[1]=%p\n", ((void**)__builtin_frame_address(0))[1]);
        ((void**)__builtin_frame_address(0))[1] = return_to;
}

int alt_return_tester(void) {
        void* locs[] = { &&loc_0, &&loc_1, &&loc_2 };
        int i = 0;
        loc_0: {
                printf("@loc_0 i=%d\n", i);
                void* return_to = locs[(i++) == 0 ? 0 : 1];
                alt_return_demo(return_to);
        }
        loc_1: {
                printf("@loc_1 i=%d\n", i);
                void* return_to = locs[(i++) < 3 ? 1 : 2];
                alt_return_demo(return_to);
        }
        loc_2: {
                printf("@loc_2 i=%d\n", i);
                return 0;
        }
}

int main(void) {
        return alt_return_tester();
}
```

When you run it, you should see it print `@loc_0` twice, `@loc_1` twice, and then `@loc_2` once.

Keep in mind this is completely non-portable – as well as relying on GCC extensions, it also relies on the fact that the return address is the pointer after the frame pointer – I've tested that this code works on x86-64 Linux and x86-64 macOS, but quite likely will not on some other operating systems or CPU architectures. These GCC extensions are also implemented by Clang, and probably some other C/C++ compilers too, but certainly not all. Also, increasingly compilers and operating systems have integrity mechanisms to stop exploits from tampering with return addresses on the stack, and there is a good chance those mechanisms will conflict with this technique (whether now or in the future).

The code above is also using `__builtin_return_address`, but that's not required to make it work, just to print some debugging info. (Demonstrate that pointer after frame pointer is the same value as return address.)

In my testing this only works with `void` functions. The problem with using it with a function that returns a value, is that for these lines:

```
    return_value = alt_return_demo(return_to);
loc_1:
```

GCC generates this assembly (for a 32-bit return value):

```
        call    alt_return_demo
        movl    %eax, -44(%rbp)
.L5:
```

The `loc_1` (which in the above assembly turned into `.L5`) is *after* the instruction which copies the return value (in `%eax`) into a local variable. Clang's assembly is the same. I'm not aware of any way in GCC or Clang to create a label which points to immediately after the `call` instruction, but without that, you can't reliably get the return value.

Okay, well you can with an ugly hack – a 32-bit `movl %eax, -N(%rbp)` is 3 bytes long, and a 64-bit `movq %rax, -N(%rbp)` is 4 bytes long, so just subtract 3 or 4 bytes from the `return_to` address. However, that is extremely fragile, since any change in the assembler output generated by the compiler will break it. I think it is better just to force all "alternate return" functions to be `void`, and use an output parameter (pointer in C, in C++ either a pointer or reference) instead.